# Change the default audio and video codec loaded by avformat_alloc_output_context2

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg library for live streaming via RTMP. I want to know how to give my choice of audio and video codec for the particular format in avformat_alloc_output_context2.

In Detail:

The following command works perfectly for me.

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i ~/Downloads/Microsoft_Surface.mp4 -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -strict -2 -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://192.168.1.7/live/surface
```

In the output, I have set my audio codec to be aac and copied the video codec from input, which is H264.
I want to emulate this in the library, but don't know how to.

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&_ctx, NULL, "flv", NULL);
```

Above code sets oformat audio codec to ADPCM_SWF and video codec to FLV1. How to change that to AAC and H264 ?

So far, used av_guess_format to construct AVOutputFormat. It accepts only format as input.  And I don't know where to mention audio and video codec.

```
AVOutputFormat* output_format = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
```

Also tried giving filename to avformat_alloc_output_context2 with the rest of the parameters NULL.

```
AVOutputFormat* output_format = av_guess_format(NULL, "flv_acc_sample.flv", NULL);
```

This file has AAC audio and H264 video. But still ffmpeg loads oformat with ADPCM_SWF audio and FLV1 video codecs.

Searched stackoverflow for similar questions, but could not find the solution I was looking for.
Any hint/guidance is hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add streams and then set encoders. Study https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. 
I have found a workaround. Don't know if this is the correct way of doing this though.
Created AVOutputFormat using  "AVOutputFormat* oformat = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL)" and then manually edited the audio and video codec fields in "oformat" before giving it to avformat_alloc_output_context2.
It works and I'm able to stream audio and video.